# What route predicate means in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I was using `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()` method where I came across `RoutePredicate`.

I can't find a perfect explanation for `RoutePredicate` anywhere.

Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> A predicate is a function that takes one item as input and returns
> either true or false based on whether the item satisfies some
> condition.

A route predicate is a function that removes routes until one with a certain name is found. The `Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil()` will stop execution if the predicate returns true, otherwise it will continue to remove routes if the predicate returns false.

To remove all the routes below the pushed route, use a RoutePredicate that always returns false.
example-

```
Navigator.of(context)
    .pushNamedAndRemoveUntil('/login', (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
```

Here using a RoutePredicate that always returns false `(Route<dynamic> route) => false`. In this situation it removes all of the routes except for the new `/login` route which is pushed.

reference - https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushNamedAndRemoveUntil.html

Comment: what is the meaning of `dynamic` and why do we add it?

Comment: @AdityaDixit `Route<T>`, The type argument `T` is the route's return type,
The `dynamic` keyword declares a variable of the type ‘dynamic’ with optional typing. It marks a variable as 'not type checked'.